# ClassCastException when using Kotlin + progurad in Android project

Tags: android, kotlin

code:

```
private val mediaPlayerListener by lazy { InnerMediaPlayerListener() }

inner class InnerMediaPlayerListener : PlayerListenerCallback {
// ...
}
```

kotlin version: 1.2.60

It runs fine in debug build but throws a ClassCastException in release build:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: xxx.xxx.FooClass$mediaPlayerListener$2 cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0`

Then I decompiled the .class from release build:

```
final class QQMusicAudioPlayer$mediaPlayerListener$2 extends Lambda
```

So the question is:

Why `QQMusicAudioPlayer$mediaPlayerListener$2` not implements `Function0` but extends `Lambda` instead in release build? the compiler behaves differently between debug and release build?